# Windows 7 menu color

Tags: windows-7, accessibility

I find the Windows 7 menu quite hard to differentiate. The default background color and highlighted background color are too similar:

[image]

Can I change this without changing the actual theme? Or do I need to choose a high-contrast theme?

Answer (score 2):

I went through the detailed Window Color and Appearance (...Icon, IconSpacing, Inactive Title Bar, Inactive Window Border, ...), and it's just not possible with Aero themes (the pretty glassy effects).

However, yes, you are right, a high-contrast theme will change this menu highlight color for you.

Comment: +1 I did this too and couldn't find anything either.

Answer (score 1):

There's a software I think you might be interested in:
[My colors](http://stardock.com/products/mycolors/) - Stardock.com

Comment: Do you need to install StarDock to use the My Colors?

Comment: "My Colors" is badly named, as it is rather a concatenation of Stardock products (Windowblinds, iconpackager, etc) to provide you with full fixed "themes" (different commercial approach, instead of buying a customizing software for a particular element (windows, icons,...), with free content from their site, you have the program for free, but the themes are to pay individually for). I don't think it allows you to actually change colors.

Comment: @rlb.usa I don't think so, it came with my lappy, I don't see any Stardock. :)

Comment: @rlb.usa:  Stardock is the company making the app, not an application itself.  Most (all?) of their software requires that the impulse client be installed to download it.